# How to check if a text field is not empty in Java & contains Integer value?

Tags: java, parsing

I have a GUI which stores the Bank Account number, during validation, I need to check if the user has entered the account number.

For string fields, isEmpty() method can be used, but what about Integer field account number.

```
Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText()).isEmpty()
```

would give an error, How to check for null fields when its an Integer?

Comment: What integer value should you get by parsing an empty string?

Comment: You should also consider using a `JSpinner` or `JFormattedField` as they can auto validate the content based on your needs.  You could also use `DocumentFilter` to filter what the user inputs into the field in real time, further limiting what the user can enter

Answer (score 3):

Check is Empty before parsing it into integer like

```
if(!jTextField1.getText().isEmpty()){

Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should rather try the following code

```
if(!(jTextField1.getText().isEmpty()))
    {
        int accountNumber=Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Class `Integer` is just an wrapper on top of primitive `int` type. So it can either be `null` or store a valid integer value. There is no obvious "empty" definition for it.

If you just compare `Integer` against empty `String`, you''ll get `false` as a result. Always. See `Integer.equals(Object o)` implementation:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

**First of all, you can get a `NumberFormatException` during parsing integer in the line:**

`Integer accountNumber = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText())`

**And you are getting it, since `For input string: ""` looks like a `NumberFormatExpection` message.**

In your example you should either check whether the `"accountNumber"` attribute value is a number (assume it's a string) and then parse it, or parse it as is and catch `NumberFormatException` that `Integer.parseInt()` throws on incorrect argument.

**First solution:**

```
if(!jTextField1.getText().isEmpty() && jTextField1.getText().matches("\\d+")){ //null-check and regex check to make sure the string contains only 
     Integer accountNumber = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());                 
}
```

**Second solution:**

```
try{
     Integer accountNumber = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());                 
}catch (NumberFormatException e) {
// handle error
```

}

Hope this should help you.

P.S. If you use Java of version 7 or higher, consider use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to manage `Connection` and `PreparedStatement`.